# Which compiler is used to compile java class to .dex

Tags: android, compiler-construction

Which compiler is used to convert java class files into dex files? As I understand, the DVM offers JIT, is it the DVM that performs the compilation then? Anybody sources on a more in-depth description about the compilation process on Android would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the dexer tool (dx) is a tool bundled with the Android SDK that converts the class files into dex files. Unfortunately, there isn't much information available about the process of how DVM deals with dex files.  However, it's important to note that JIT was only bundled with DVM starting in Android 2.2 which means that it probably isn't involved in the conversion between class files to dex files.